# bilateral filtering code. but there is a problem with the main part and bilateral part

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

```
`import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

def my_padding(src, pad_shape, pad_type='zero'):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    (p_h, p_w) = pad_shape
    pad_img = np.zeros((h+2*p_h, w+2*p_w))
    pad_img[p_h:p_h+h, p_w:p_w+w] = src

    if pad_type == 'repetition':
        print('repetition padding')
        #up
        pad_img[:p_h, p_w:p_w+w] = src[0, :]
        #down
        pad_img[p_h+h:, p_w:p_w+w] = src[h-1, :]

        #left
        pad_img[:,:p_w] = pad_img[:, p_w:p_w + 1]
        #right
        pad_img[:, p_w+w:] = pad_img[:, p_w+w-1:p_w+w]

    return pad_img

def my_filtering(src, filter, pad_type='zero'):
    (h, w) = src.shape
    (f_h, f_w) = filter.shape
    src_pad = my_padding(src, (f_h//2, f_w//2), pad_type)
    dst = np.zeros((h, w))

    for row in range(h):
        for col in range(w):
            val = np.sum(src_pad[row:row+f_h, col:col+f_w] * filter)
            dst[row, col] = val

    return dst

def my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(msize, sigma=1):
    y, x = np.mgrid[-(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1, -(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1]

    
    gaus2D =   1 / (2 * np.pi * sigma**2) * np.exp(-(( x**2 + y**2 )/(2 * sigma**2)))
    
    gaus2D /= np.sum(gaus2D)

    return gaus2D

def my_normalize(src):
    dst = src.copy()
    dst *= 255
    dst = np.clip(dst, 0, 255)
    return dst.astype(np.uint8)

def add_gaus_noise(src, mean=0, sigma=0.1):
    #src : 0 ~ 255, dst : 0 ~ 1
    dst = src/255
    h, w = dst.shape
    noise = np.random.normal(mean, sigma, size=(h, w))
    dst += noise
    return my_normalize(dst)

def my_bilateral(src, msize, sigma, sigma_r, pos_x, pos_y, pad_type='zero'):
    
    (h, w) = src.shape
    m_s = (msize-1)//2
    img_pad = my_padding(src, (m_s//2, m_s//2), pad_type)
    dst = np.zeros((h,w))

    y, x = np.mgrid[-(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1, -(msize // 2):(msize // 2) + 1]

    for i in range(h):
        print('\r%d / %d ...' %(i,h), end="")
        for j in range(w):
            mask = np.exp(-((x-j)**2 + (y-i)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
            mask /= np.sum(mask)

            if i==pos_y and j == pos_x:
                print()
                print(mask.round(4))
                img = img_pad[i:i+5, j:j+5]
                img = cv2.resize(img, (200, 200), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
                img = my_normalize(img)

            dst[i, j] = np.sum(img_pad[i:i+msize, j:j+msize]*mask)

    return dst



if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    src = cv2.imread('Lenna.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    np.random.seed(seed=100)

    pos_y = 0
    pos_x = 0
    src_noise = add_gaus_noise(src, mean=0, sigma=0.1)
    src_noise = src_noise/255

    dst = my_bilateral(src_noise, 5, 10, 0.1, pos_x, pos_y)
    dst = my_normalize(dst)

    gaus2D = my_get_Gaussian2D_mask(5 , sigma = 1)
    dst_gaus2D= my_filtering(src_noise, gaus2D)
    dst_gaus2D = my_normalize(dst_gaus2D)

    cv2.imshow('original', src)
    cv2.imshow('gaus noise', src_noise)
    cv2.imshow('my gaussian', dst_gaus2D)
    cv2.imshow('my bilateral', dst)
    tital_time = time.time() - start
    print('\ntime : ', tital_time)
    if tital_time > 25:
        print('please change code')
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

I would like to make a code that performs bilateral filtering.

The other functions are the completed parts,
I’d like to make a code that performs bilateral filtering by modifying only the function ‘my_bilatera’ and ‘main’.
but
line 101, in
src_noise = add_gaus_noise(src, mean=0, sigma=0.1)

line 56, in add_gaus_noise
dst = src/255
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: ‘NoneType’ and ‘int’
There are errors.

I’m probably getting an error due to the size of the image during the mask filter process, how do I fix it?
The path where the image is stored was performed without any problems.
I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how to modify it.
I uploaded it because I couldn’t process it quickly due to lack of knowledge.
I will study more if you let me know.
thank you…

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/bilateral-filtering/13150